# Oracle query with multiple joins taking far too long to run

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I'm trying to develop a table which involves three tables. TB3 has 500k records, TBL6 has 10 million records and TBL2, TBL4, TBL5 has 20 million records and are the same table. TBL1 is a subquery with a number of joins. I cannot change the database structure but have checked the indices available and that hasn't helped. I've used the OUTER APPLY join at the end as I thought that may speed up my performance but after much experimenting I still and up killing the query after 15-20 minutes.

```
SELECT TBL1.START_TIME,
   TBL1.DEST_TIME,
   TBL1.SRCADDRESS,
   TBL1.POS,
   TBL2.ADDRESSID AS TBL2 FROM (
SELECT TBL3.EVENTTIME,
   TBL3.SOURCEADDRESS,
   TBL6.FROM_POS,
   TBL3.LC_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER_OVERVIEW_V TBL3
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_SALE_RELATED TBL6 ON TBL6.LC_NAME = TBL3.LC_NAME 
                              AND TBL6.FROM_LOC = TBL3.SOURCEADDRESS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER TBL4 ON TBL4.CUSTID = TBL3.LC_NAME
                                         AND TBL4.AREATYPE = 'SW'
                                         AND TBL4.EVENTTIME <= TBL3.EVENTTIME + interval '1' second
                                         AND TBL4.EVENTTIME >= TBL3.EVENTTIME - interval '1' second
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER TBL5 ON CUSTID = TBL3.LC_NAME
                                         AND TBL5.AREATYPE = 'SE'   
                                         AND TBL5.EVENTTIME <= TBL3.EVENTTIME + interval '1' second
                                         AND TBL5.EVENTTIME >= TBL3.EVENTTIME - interval '1' second                                         
WHERE TBL3.SOURCEADDRESS IS NOT NULL
AND extract(second from TBL5.EVENTTIME - TBL4.EventTime) * 1000 > 250
ORDER BY TBL3.EVENTTIME DESC
FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY) TBL1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ADDRESSID
         FROM CUSTOMER 
         WHERE AREATYPE = 'STH'
         AND EVENTTIME > TBL1.DEST_TIME
         ORDER BY EVENTTIME ASC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) TBL2;
```

There must be a way to structure this query better to improve the performance so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to run an explain plan and post the results

Comment: In addition to my answer below, you have another option if you are unable to get it work as I outlined:  create a materialized view or derived table using your SQL, but without limiting the number of rows. Use hash joins and full table scans with parallel query (and don't use OUTER APPLY, as that will use nested loops). Once your results are sitting in a table segment, you can index the eventtime column and your front-end can query it (still using index_desc hint and proper ORDER BY DESC clause). It'll be much easier to get it to work on a simple table if you can't do it with your original SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the first 500 rows, so you only want a tiny fraction of your overall data. Therefore you want to use nested loops joins with appropriate indexes in order to get those 500 rows and be done, rather than have to process millions of rows and only then take off the top 500.

That however is complicated by the fact that you want the first 500 after ordering results. That ORDER BY will require a sort, and a sort operation will have to process 100% of the incoming rows in order to produce even its first row of output, which means you have to crunch 100% of your data and that kills your performance.

*If* your inner joins to TBL6, TBL4 and TBL5 are not meant to drop rows that don't have a matching key (e.g. if making those outer joins would result in the same # of result rows from TBL3), *and if* you don't really need to filter on `extract(second from TBL5.EVENTTIME - TBL4.EventTime) * 1000 > 250` which requires a join of TBL5 and TBL4 to accomplish, *and if* this `CUSTOMER_OVERVIEW_V` view is a simple single-table view that doesn't apply any predicates (not likely), or if you can bypass the view and hit the table directly, then you can do this:

1. Create a 2-column function-based index (e.g. `customer_eventtime_idx`) on `(DECODE(sourceaddress,NULL,'Y','N'),eventtime)` of table you need from the `customer_overview_v` view, in that exact column order.
2. Rewrite the query to get the 500 rows as early as possible, preferably before any joins, using a hint to force a descending index scan on this index. You will also need to change your IS NOT NULL predicate to the same DECODE function used in the index definition:

   ```
   SELECT /*+ LEADING(c) USE_NL(csr c1 c2 adr) */
          [columns needed]
     FROM (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE INDEX_DESC(x customer_eventtime_idx) */
                  [columns you need]
             FROM TABLE_UNDER_CUSTOMER_OVERVIEW_V x
            WHERE DECODE(SOURCEADDRESS,NULL,'Y','N') = 'N'
            ORDER BY DECODE(SOURCEADDRESS,NULL,'Y','N') DESC,EVENTTIME DESC
            FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY) c
          INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_SALE_RELATED ... csr
          INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ... c1
          INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ... c2
          OUTER APPLY ([address subquery like you have it]) adr
    WHERE extract(second from c.EVENTTIME - c1.EventTime) * 1000 > 250
   ```

Generate your explain plan and make sure you see the `index scan descending` operation on the index you created - it *must* say descending, and also ensure that you see `ORDER BY NOSORT` step afterwards... it *must* say NOSORT. Creating the index as we have and ordering our query as we have was all about getting these plan operations to be selected. This is not easy to get to work right. Every detail around the inner `c` query must be crafted precisely to achieve the trick.

**Explanation**:

Oracle should seek/access the index on the DECODE Y/N result, so find the N records (those that have a non-null sourceaddress) in the first column of the index starting at the leading edge of the N values, then get the corresponding row from the table, then step backward to the pervious N value, get that table row, then the previous, etc.. emitting rows as they are found. Because the ORDER BY matches the index exactly in the same direction (descending), Oracle will skip the SORT operation as it knows that the data coming out of the index step will already be in the correct order.

These rows therefore stream out of the `c` inline view as they are found, which allows the FETCH FIRST to stop processing when it gets too 500 rows of output without having to wait for any buffering operation (like a SORT) to complete. You only ever hit those 500 records - it never visits the rest of the rows.

You then join via nested loops to the remaining tables, but you only have 500 driving rows. Obviously you must ensure appropriate indexing on those tables for your join clauses.

If your CUSTOMER_ORDER_V view however does joins and applies more predicates, you simply cannot do this with the view. You will have to use the base tables and apply this trick on whatever base table has that eventtime column, then join in whatever you need that the view was joining to and reproduce any remaining needed view logic (though you might find it does more than you need, and you can omit much of it). In general, don't use views whenever you can help it. You always have more control against base tables.

Lastly, note that I did not follow your TBL1, TBL2, TBL3, etc. alias convention. That is hard to read because you have to constantly look elsewhere to see what "TBL3" means. Far better to use aliases that communicate immediately what table they are, such as the initial letter or couple letters or acronym from the first letter of each word, etc..